# How to user vpc endpoint for ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

I would like to create a lambda(vpc) which would access resources in vpc and make a request to services(REST API) via public application load balancer. I found out that vpc end point is better solution than creating a nat gateway.

I have created a vpc endpoint for elasticloadbalancing(by following steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#create-interface-endpoint) and given full access in the policy. I could not find how to access it from the lambda, what would be the URL to make the request?

Edit:
Thanks to John for the info that vpc endpoint is used to connect to ELB API. So Vpc endpoint would not solve our issue.
We have our infra in vpc which includes database(accessible within vpc only) and application servers running behind the ELB. For certain tasks we want to run lambda which will read database(for this reason lambda has to be inside vpc) and make API calls to our application using ELB. Since ELB is accessible from public dns only, lambda is not able to connect to ELB.

I have read that setting up NAT gateway is a solution. Are there other is simpler ways?

Comment: Please note that the interface VPC endpoint is used to connect to the **Load Balancing API** (which is used to manage the Load Balancer), _not_ for traffic that goes through the Load Balancer. Could you please tell us more about the architecture you wish to build? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Comment of @JohnRotenstein should be in the docs for the endpoints. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a NAT Gateway would allow the traffic from a private subnet to go out of the VPC and come back in to the Load Balancer's public IP addresses (via its Public DNS Name).

Alternatively, you could create an additional *Internal* Load Balancer that could accept traffic from within the VPC and send it to the Amazon EC2 instances.